# How can I refactor the validation code to minimize it?

Tags: python, django

I am using Django Rest Framework and below is the code of one of the API Endpoints. The code creates generates the PUBLIC and SECRET Values based on Stellar SDK.

```
def create(self, request):
        try:
            if 'app_id' not in request.data:
                response = {'status': 'FAIL', 'data': 'App ID field not found'}
                return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

            if 'customer_id' not in request.data:
                response = {'status': 'FAIL', 'data': 'Customer ID field not found'}
                return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

            customer_id = request.data['customer_id']
            app_id = request.data['app_id']
            app = App.objects.get(id=app_id)

            # Creating Stellar Account
            addr, secret = create_account()

            if addr is None and secret is None:
                response = {'status': 'FAIL', 'data': 'Could not generate customer Wallet'}
                return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

            # Make sure we do not add duplicate customers
            wallet_count = Wallet.objects.filter(customer_id=customer_id).count()
            if wallet_count > 0:
                response = {'status': 'FAIL', 'data': 'The customer ID already exist'}
                return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

            # The customer does not exist, hence create his wallet.
            wallet = Wallet(customer_id=customer_id, app=app, address=addr, secret=secret)
            wallet.save()

            if wallet.pk is None and wallet.pk > 0:
                response = {'status': 'OK', 'data': 'success'}
            else:
                response = {'status': 'FAIL', 'data': 'Messed up'}
        except App.DoesNotExist:
            response = {'status': 'FAIL', 'data': 'The App ID not found'}
            return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        return Response({'status': 'OK', 'data': 'success'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

As you can see there is repetition of codeblock like below:

```
response = {'status': 'FAIL', 'data': 'The customer ID already exist'}
                return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

It'd be nice if I can reduce all this code either by passing to a function or someway once and let it handle based on `request` dict.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. I have rolled back your edit. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4):

## Exception handling

You may want to consider reducing the try block to where the expected exception actually is raised.

```
try:
    app = App.objects.get(id=app_id)
except App.DoesNotExist:
    …
```

## Possible bugs

This test does not consider the case, that *only one* of `addr` and `secret` is `None`. Is that permitted?

```
if addr is None and secret is None:
    …
```

These response dicts are never used:

```
if wallet.pk is None and wallet.pk > 0:
    response = {'status': 'OK', 'data': 'success'}
else:
    response = {'status': 'FAIL', 'data': 'Messed up'}
```

## Deduplication

Regarding your concern of duplicated dicts: I see none.
Sure, they are *similar*, but there are no duplicates, since the error messages differ. Of course, you can outsource the generation to a function like

```
def make_response(data: str, success: bool) -> dict:
    """Returns a response dict."""
    return {'status': 'OK' if success else 'FAIL', 'data': data}
```

but it's up to you to decide if that's worth an extra function.

Comment: Thanks, Richard, your first two recommendations implemented/fixed however did not get the dedup one. Could you check the updated question?

Comment: You could drop the response variable, and just return - it simplifies this a bit, e.g. : return Response({'status': 'FAIL', 'data': 'Customer ID field not found'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

Comment: I thought of writing a function to use like `return fail_with('Customer ID field not found', status.HTTP_404_BAD_REQUEST)`